# In Numpy, how to remove a dimension of size 0?

Tags: python, numpy

In Numpy I have an array A of shape `(1, 48, 48, 0)`.

How do I remove the last dimension of size 0 ? I.e. I want to have `(1, 48, 48)`.

I have tried:

```
A = A[:-1]
```

But it returns an array of shape: `(0, 48, 48, 0)`

Any idea ?

p.s: I am actually wondering what it means for an array to have a dimension of size 0 ...

Comment: It means your array is empty, only empty arrays can have a dimension equal to 0. What does `A.size` give you?

Comment: You can use A = A[0:3]

Comment: You can't.  The first has 0 elements.  The target `48*48`.  You can't create those from nothing.  How did you get that array?

Comment: The total number of elements of an array is the product of its dimensions.  A (2,3) shape has 6 elements.  A (2,3,0) shape has 0.  That last can be reshaped to (6,0), or anything as long as there's a 0 in the shape.